# Running Batch file from servers network share - using servers local user account

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am trying to create a script that could be run from servers network share and promt me to type servers local username and password as credentials.

So, .bat file is located at \SERVER\INSTALL\Windows XP\RUN.bat

I want to be able to run "run.bat" from any system in the network without opening cmd.exe as different user. Just double click run.bat from the servers share and it starts up second batch - if credentials are OK.

This is how far i could get. I launch the RUN.bat batch containing lines

```
runas /env /user:SERVER\USER "\\SERVER\INSTALL\Windows XP\install.bat
```

And this should launch the second batch containing the full script, that works fine individually.

When Run.bat  asks to type the password for USER - there is an error. Bad username or wrong password. (Local user is created on the server and has enough permissions)

Comment: This cannot work if the account doesn't exist locally. Please explain what you're planning to do with the login. Access a network share, perhaps?

Comment: By the way. It works fine using a domain\user

Comment: Yes i want to access the share, using servers local user, where the file is hosted on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639743/batch-script-to-run-as-administrator - This actually helped me to get my answer.

Comment: i did it myself :) added

runas /env /netonly /user:DFIU "<File>"

Comment: If you found an answer by yourself, please post it as an answer. You can then accept this answer after a certain time. This way, this question can be marked as answered.